# How to edit script filter in this madule of opencart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart2.x, opencart-module

In the file `filter.tpl` in `madule` filters.

When select checkbox for filter, example: `color=blue` and `size=3inch` with `filter_id=365,367`, show all product with `filter_id=356` or `filter_id=367`, show all product with `filter_id` in (365,367).

Now I want to select checkbox blue and size 3 (multi select), show only product with `color=blue` and `size=3` and not show product with color blue or size 3.

If need to other data, say.

Help me for understand javascript code. Description for each line.

`opencart 2.3.0.2`

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="list-group">
    <?php foreach ($filter_groups as $filter_group) { ?>
    <a class="list-group-item"><?php echo $filter_group['name']; ?></a>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <div id="filter-group<?php echo $filter_group['filter_group_id']; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($filter_group['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <?php if (in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
            <?php echo $filter['name']; ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" />
            <?php echo $filter['name']; ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </label>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer text-right">
    <button type="button" id="button-filter" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $button_filter; ?></button>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-filter').on('click', function() {
    filter = [];

    $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
        filter.push(this.value);
    });

    location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
});
//--></script>
```

Comment: What is your OC version?

Comment: opencart 2.3.0.2

Comment: no anyone????????????